# Plot function with 2 variables in tikz / pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Using `Tikz` / `pgfplots`, how can you plot a function with two variables, such as:
`|x| + |y| <= 1 / sqrt(2)`?

If the function only had one input,`X`, it is easy to plot:

```
\begin{figure}[!hb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=-10000:10000, blue, ultra thick] {abs(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Plot of $\abs(x)$}
\end{figure}
```

However, the following produces an error

```
\addplot[domain=-10000:10000, blue, ultra thick] {abs(x) + abs(y) <= 1 / sqrt(2)};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a parametrization (well, two in this case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
domain=-1/sqrt(2):1/sqrt(2),
samples=400,
xmin=-1.5,
xmax=1.5,
ymin=-1.5,
ymax=1.5,
axis on top=true
]
\addplot+[mark=none,cyan,fill] ({x},{max(1/sqrt(2)-abs(x),0)}) \closedcycle;
\addplot+[mark=none,cyan,fill] ({x},{min(abs(x)-1/sqrt(2),0)}) \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With PSTricks' implicit plot macro:

```
\psplotImp[<options>](-2,-2)(2,2){abs(x)+abs(y)-const}
```

The Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pstVerb{/const 1 2 sqrt div def}%
    \pspolygon*[linecolor=cyan](!const 0)(!0 const)(!const neg 0)(!0 const neg)
    \psplotImp[linecolor=red,algebraic,stepFactor=0.1](-2,-2)(2,2){abs(x)+abs(y)-const}
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Algorithm

The following animation discloses the confidential algorithm used (by `\psplotImp`) behind the scene.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}
\multido{\r=1.5+-0.1}{15}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
  \pstVerb{/const 1 2 sqrt div def}%
  \psplotImp[linecolor=red,algebraic,stepFactor=\r](-1,-1)(1,1){abs(x)+abs(y)-const}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

`MWE` with `Asymptote`, using a `contour` module.

Some comments: the boundary is constructed as
`guide g=(contour(f,(-1,-1),(1,1), new real[]{1/sqrt(2)}))[0][0];`,
where expression `new real[]{1/sqrt(2)}` stands for an in-line array of level values,
(in this case just one, `1/sqrt(2)`). The trailing `[0][0]` means that in general
there are a matrix of curves returned, where the first index corresponds 
to the index in the levels array, and the second index counts the curves 
that correspond to the particular level value.

```
% imp.tex :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
size(300);
import graph;
import contour;
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
pen bgColor=paleyellow;
real f(pair v){return abs(v.x)+abs(v.y);};
guide g=(contour(f,(-1,-1),(1,1), new real[]{1/sqrt(2)}))[0][0];
pen linePen=deepblue+1bp;
pen fillPen=deepblue+opacity(0.3);
pen xyPen=darkblue+0.4bp;
filldraw(g,fillPen,linePen);
real du=0.02;
xaxis(-0.8-du,0.8+du,xyPen, LeftTicks(OmitTick(0),Step=0.2,step=0.1),above=true);
yaxis(-0.8-du,0.8+du,xyPen,RightTicks(OmitTick(0),Step=0.2,step=0.1),above=true);
shipout(bbox(Fill(bgColor)));
\end{asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
%% Process:
%
% pdflatex imp.tex 
% asy -f pdf imp-*.asy     
% pdflatex imp.tex
```